# Cannot access data from row after destroying and reinitializing datatable when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

After looking endlessly I cannot see what is going wrong here.

My Javascript and HTML:

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/', 
          type: 'POST', 
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify(arr),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function(response){
            response = buildPhotoString(response);

            populateTable(response);
          }
        }
      );

 function populateTable(response){
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#dataTable' ) ) {
      var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
      table.destroy();
    }
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        data: response,
        columns: [
          { data: 'number' },
          { data: null,
            render: function(data, type, rows){
              return '<div class="btn-group"> <button id="b_Hoog" class="btn btn-md btn-success pull-left "> Hoogbouw</button> <button id="b_Laag" class="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-right"> Laagbouw</button> </div>';
            }
          },
          { data: 'photo'}
        ]
    });

  $('#dataTable').on( 'click', 'tbody #b_Hoog', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
    updateDB('Hoogbouw', data.number );
  });
  $('#dataTable').on( 'click', 'tbody #b_Laag', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
    updateDB('Laagbouw', data.number );
  });
  }
```

And html:

```
body
  table(id='dataTable' class="table table-striped")
   thead
    th= 'Referentie'
    th= ' '
    th= 'Foto'
   tbody
```

Basically, the DataTable draws fine regardless of the number of times the function populateTable is called. However, data is *undefined* when either button b_Hoog or b_Laag is pressed after populateTable has been called more than once. The first time it works just fine. table.row.data does return always data however. The exact error i get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: adding index() to the line below fixed the damn thing

```
var data = table.row( $(this).closest('tr').index() ).data();
```

Comment: You're recycling the same ID in your markup: your IDs must be unique.

Comment: Okay, deleting the ID's for the buttons and replacing tbody #b_Hoog to the respective classes of the buttons does not fix it sadly.

Comment: That's not your only problem. However, it's difficult to see what has gone wrong unless you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example.